# Reading order for Bionicle

Tags: suggested-order, bionicle

What is the proper reading order for the various novels, comics, and movies that make up Bionicle?

(I am asking about the old continuity, not the 2015 reboot.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the order of the old Bionicle canon stories follows the chronological order of release as most of the stories cover aspects that require past knowledge from previous years so here is a summary:

**Mata Nui**

*Bionicle Comics 1 - 15* (2001-2002) + *Bionicle Chronicles* (2001-2003) + *Bionicle: Mask of Light (Film)* (2003)

The story themes from this era are:

- 2001: *The Coming of the Toa*
- 2002: *The Bohrok Swarms*
- 2003: *The Bohrok-Kai Strike* then *Mask of Light*

**Metru Nui**

*Bionicle Comics 16 - 27* (2004) + *Bionicle Adventures* (2004-2005) + *Bionicle: Legends of Metru Nui (Film)* + *Bionicle: Web of Shadows (Film)*

The story themes from this era are:

- 2004: *Legends of Metru Nui*
- 2005: *The Great Rescue*

**Quest for the Mask of Life**

The Quest for the Mask of Life can be split into three sections *Voya Nui*, *Mahri Nui* and *Karda Nui*.

***Voya Nui***

*Bionicle: Ignition* (2006) + *Bionicle Legends: 1 - 5* (2006)

***Mahri Nui***

*Bionicle: Sea of Darkness* (2007) + *Bionicle Legends: 6 - 8* (2006-2007)

*Serials:* Dreams of Destruction (2007), Into the Darkness (2007), Toa Nuva Blog (2007)

***Karda Nui***

*Bionicle: Battle for Power* (2008) + *Bionicle Legends: 9 - 11* (2008)

*Serials:* The Mutran Chronicles (2008), Dark Mirror (2008), Federation of Fear (2008), Destiny War (2008), Dwellers in Darkness (2008), Brothers in Arms (2008), Takanuva's Blog (2008)

**Bara Magna**

*Bionicle: Glatorian* (2009) + *Journey's End* (2010) + *Bionicle: The Legend Reborn* (2009)

*Serials:* Empire of the Skrall (2009), Reign of Shadows (2009), Riddle of the Great Beings (2009), Mata Nui Saga (2010), Sahmad's Tale (2010)

The story themes for this era are:

- Bara Magna + The Legend Reborn
- Journey's End

**Post Journey's End**

*Serials:* The Yesterday Quest (2010), The Powers that Be (2010)

For more information I would recomnend visiting these pages on the Bionicle wiki:

- http://biosector01.com/wiki/index.php/Comics
- http://biosector01.com/wiki/index.php/Books
- http://biosector01.com/wiki/index.php/Saga_Guides
- http://biosector01.com/wiki/index.php/Timeline
- http://biosector01.com/wiki/index.php/Serials
- http://biosector01.com/wiki/index.php/BIONICLEsector01:Sources

**Edit:** Added Serials